# What is the origin and meaing of the term "Telescoping Series"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-history

I looked into Carl. B. Boyer and Morris Kline books of math history, some calculus books like Apostol and Swokowski, many pages on the internet and even the Tractatus de Seriebus Infinitis of Jacobi Bernoulli with no sucess to find out the origin and meaning of the term "Telescoping Series".

May someone help?

Comment: The dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: It refers to the collapsing feature of old  telescopes, a telescoping series "collapses" to its first and last term

Comment: @Blue oh, I didn't know of that branch. I'll ask there. Shall I delete this one or keep both? Not sure of the etiquette.

Comment: @Sam do you have any reference to that? And, by collapsing you mean they get "compact" when you squeeze?

Comment: @CarlosEduardo: HSM.SE is relatively new. ... Anyway, since no one has answered this question, it would be best to delete it. Cheers!

Comment: Not listed in https://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html, surprisingly.

Comment: If you delete, I can copy-paste my answer over there.

Answer (score 6):

Picture an old telescope (a.k.a. spyglass) that is retractable.
[image: Retractable telescope]

When the terms of a series contain differences, internal terms can be canceled, much like the segments of the telescope overlapping as it is contracted. For example, using the identity
$$
\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}, 
$$
\begin{alignat*}{8}
\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} 
+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1) \cdot n} 
&= \frac{1}{1} &{}- \frac{1}{2} & & & & & \\
& & {}+ \frac{1}{2} &{}- \frac{1}{3} & & & & \\
& & & {}+ \frac{1}{3} & &{}- \frac{1}{4} & & \\ 
& & & & & & \ddots & \\
& & & & & & & {}+ \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} \\
&= 1 \rlap{{}- \frac{1}{n}} & & & & & &
\end{alignat*}

Comment: I have asked on HSM.SE and cited you about the meaning. Later on I shall delete this question. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-telescoping-series. Thanks for the answer. I understand the meaning now.